# How to re-route the user to a main page

Tags: html, .net, routes

I have .html file inside a directory "/country/main.html". Now, I want to redirect the user to this page whenever a request arrive for any country. I have written a little code snippet

```
  public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
            if (app.Request.Path.Contains("/country"))
            {
                app.Context.RewritePath("/country/main.html");
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried this url http://www.mydomain.com/country, that works fine. But if the request arrive something like this http://www.mydomain.com/country/new_york.html, it gives me 404 error.

Please suggest, what I have to do in that case?

Comment: Don't do this, it's extremely annoying. Your URLs should be persistent, so people can bookmark them.

Comment: OK. Then please suggest, how can I create the .html file for which the request arrive on the fly, bind it's content dynamically and show to the end user

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: It's a requirement. The url is seo friendly and I have to create them on the fly if they did not already exist.

Comment: I still don't understand. When users visit `http://www.mydomain.com/country/new_york.html`, should they be served a page with content specific to New York? When they visit `http://www.mydomain.com/country/chicago.html`, should the content be specific to Chicago? If you redirect them both tho the same URL, should the content also be the same? Which content for which URL should a search engine index?

Comment: Yes, each and every page have it's specific content. I don't want to redirect them to the same url. I want to have all the pages sit in the country folder and they must create dynamically. If you have any more question, please let me know.

Comment: Well, in that case, I think the answer is that the redirection you're trying to specify above is something you just don't want to do, and I still don't understand why you're trying to program it.

Comment: Can you please suggest, what can I do to achieve my goal? I guess, you have understood what I really want.

Comment: Here is the detailed specification. I have a list of hotels in the database. And each hotel record contain a specific filename for that hotel. I want to have all the hotel sit in the hotel folder. And all hotel pages should be created dynamically with it's specific content. Is it possible? And all pages should be .html displayed.

Comment: Your thinking is floored. The way I see it every time you request a page with country in it's url you will be redirected to main.html. I think what you are trying to acheive is routing.

Comment: Yes, Please suggest me the best possible solution. I know may be, I am in the wrong direction but open for the best solution according to my requirement.

Comment: @user2866746 : What you need, apparently, is a piece of C# code that, given a city name, will take the information from the corresponding database entries and generate the corresponding HTML page. You can then use it in two ways: 1) call it whenever someone requests the corresponding URL and return the HTML document as the response content; 2) write a standalone program that executes it for each possible city name and saves the results as HTML files on the file system, such that these files are served when the corresponding URL is called. None of these two options involve URL rewriting.